# How to loop posts from a specific category in WordPress homepage

Tags: wordpress

If I want to loop 3 posts from a specific category in index.php of WordPress than what I've to do?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to loop 3 post from a category before `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>`

Comment: Where's the `WP_Query`?

Comment: There's no query above...

Comment: The codes are default "Underscores" index.php codes.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
 $args = array(
     'cat' => <your category ID>,
     'posts_per_page' => 3
 );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 // The Loop
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        // ## write your code here..
    }
 }
```

You have to put the category ID.
If you have the category name, then use this:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 
);
```

For more information check this out:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: this code does not work. it creates a infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to get 3 posts from a specific category in the homepage. Add the following to functions.php and be sure to add the category id in the appropriate place

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {

    if( $q->is_home() && $q->is_main_query() ) {

        $q->set( 'cat', CATEGORY_ID );
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );

    }

});
```